# I want to get my input with selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, webdriver, alert

I need to input a onetime password so I coded as below to make alert.

```
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
$driver.execute_script("window.promptResponse=prompt('Enter the onetime password')")
alert = $driver.switch_to.alert
sleep 5
alert.accept
input = $driver.execute_script("return window.promptResponse").to_s
p input
```

In this way, I can get my input when I enter the password and just leave it away for 5 seconds. (I mean I never click OK button)

But I can't get it when I click OK before 5 seconds pass.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you mean you manually accept the alert during test execution, before 5 seconds?

Comment: @kotoj I can already accept the alert after 5 seconds, but I want to accept it manually before 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it, because script fails before getting the input value. 
When you accept the alert manually, step `alert.accept` can't execute because there are no alert to accept. 
You shouldn't accept alert manually during automatic execution.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway